# How to give echo '<a href="view2.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a>'; in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

i got this

```
<?php
echo '<a href="view2.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a>';
?>
```

as working code in php but how can I use it in html ?
I want to use it as links in html

Comment: php code doesn't work with `.html` extension. file must have `.php` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U cant use php code in .html file. Rename .html to .php and try this

> `<a href=“view2.php?id=<?=$id?>”> <?=$name?></a>`

Comment: when use <?= $name; ?>, if u want echo string

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="view2.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
```

Comment: php code doesn't work with .html extension. file must have .php extension.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `'` after echo

```
echo '<a href="view2.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.'</a>';
```

Also make sure your file has `.php` extension not `.html`. php only works in `.php` files

**UPDATE**

If `'echo <a href="view2.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a>';` is what you truly have, look at the example above of where the first `'` should be.

Comment: Thank you all. Acually i forgot to type. That was typo. Still thank you very much

Comment: @nbajpai care to explain why you chose @ Dave's answer as it is the same as @ he11d0g. and the other answers also work and are more closer to your own code. Also note that the short tags might not be working for everyone and so the chosen answer might not be the best for the community

Comment: his answer was first and moreover we can choose only single answer earlier I chose @he11d0g's answer but then I thought it should be on first come first serve basis. Moreover I did upcount for everyone's answer. Everyone's answer was correct

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<a href="view2.php?id=<?=$id?>"><?=$name?></a>
```

Comment: Doesn't add anything new compared to @he11d0g

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.